# AN ANDROID APP KEEPS CRASHING WHEN I OPEN IT GIVES THE MESSAGE "HAS STOPPED WORKING"

Tags: android, exception, webview, crash, uiwebview

I tried to run my APP, I just ended up getting a message "MegaVidi Stopped Working", I tried to run some tests and got the following errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.megatechnologyteam.megavidi/com.megatechnologyteam.megavidi.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.megatechnologyteam.megavidi, PID: 10886
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.megatechnologyteam.megavidi/com.megatechnologyteam.megavidi.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
    at com.megatechnologyteam.megavidi.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
```

How do I solve this so that my APP can run properly?
Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Please locate the object in your code

```
com.megatechnologyteam.megavidi.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:20)
```

There should have an object of the class ActionBar attempting calling hide().

This just object is actually null. Please check.

Comment: Of course I see it as "getSupportActionBar().hide();", then how can I solve it

Answer (score 0):

In `SplashActivity` you are trying to hide the ActionBar which is `null` (that is why you are getting `NullPointerException`).

To resolve the issue, remove the line where you are calling `ActionBar.hide()`.

I cannot tell you more than this without seeing the code of `SplashActivity`.